# Why isn't my application's performance scaling with more CPUs?

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am running a piece of software that is very parallel. There are about 400 commands I need to run that don't depend on each other at all, so I just fork them off and hope and that having more CPUs means more processes executed per unit time.

Code:

```
foreach cmd ($CMD_LIST)
    $cmd &    #fork it off
end
```

Very simple. Here are my testing results:

On 1 CPU, this takes 1006 seconds, or 16 mins 46 seconds.

With 10 CPUs, this took 600s, or 10 minutes!

Why wouldn't the time taken divide (roughly) by 10? I feel cheated here =(

edit - of course I'm willing to provide additional details you would want to know, just not sure what's relevant because in simplest terms this is what I'm doing.

Comment: What are the processes doing? Are they IO-bound or CPU-bound?

Comment: This is where I'm a little unsure. They are calling "eperl" which expands text templates that contain snippets of perl code into larger files. Could be IO-bound.

Comment: Are you running on a virtual machine? Total CPU time may be capped.

Comment: yeah, it's over a VNC and I remotely request CPUs from "the farm". I don't know of any cap..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming your processes are 100% CPU-bound.

If your processes do any disk or network I/O, the bottleneck will be on those operations, which cannot be parallelised (eg one process will download a file at 100k/s, 2 processes at 50k/s each so you would not see any improvement at all, furthermore you could experience a degrade in performance because of overheads).

See: [Amdahl's_law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) - this allows you to estimate the improvement in performance when parallelising tasks, knowing the proportion between the parallelisable part and the non-parallelisable)

Comment: I see.. so for I/O-bound you're sorta hitting a wall?

Comment: Well - you are only increasing the number of CPUs - if you want a performance improvements on IO-bound operations, you have to "parallelise" IO as well, which means better disks, a RAID controller, a faster network etc.

Comment: darn, those don't sound like options in my case. I'll probably try taking a better look at each `$cmd`, seeing what data it tries accessing, and try prefetching it or something.

Comment: Provided you have plenty of memory, you could try creating a ram disk http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/ and putting the most loaded files there.

Comment: Another, possibly HUGE improvement, could be trying to launch tasks in group of 20 (two tasks per processor is a good rule of thumb) wait for those to finish and launch 20 more etc - as it is, you are running 400 processes at the same time, making the scheduler switching like crazy. If you know Java, use a fixedThreadPool with 20 threads and Runtime.exec() to launch your commands, so as soon as one of the 20 is finished another one will start

Comment: Let me know the final result :)